# How do I fix a CouchDB replication verification error?

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, replication

I tried setting up a CouchDB cluster with 3 ubuntu servers.
When verifying the installation, all tests succeed, except the last one for replication.
This is the error message I get:

Error: unauthorized to access or create database http://127.0.0.1:5984/verifytestdb_replicate/

I created a database with a document and could see it on all 3 servers. So replication seems to work...